# Mypy is not a valid type

Tags: python, mypy

I wrote the function

```py
@abc.abstractmethod
def _get_payload(
    self,
    entity_id: snowflakes.Snowflake,
    api_method: urls.API_METHODS,
    get_achievements: typing.Optional[bool] = None,
    **params: typing.Any
) -> data_binding.JSONObject:
```

and my urls.API_METHODS is

```py
API_METHODS: typing.Final[dict[str, str]] = {
    'account_info': ACCOUNT_INFO_PATH,
    'account_list': ACCOUNT_LIST_PATH,
    'account_achievements': ACCOUNT_ACHIEVEMENTS_PATH,
    'clan_info': CLAN_INFO_PATH,
    'clan_list': CLAN_LIST_PATH,
    'clan_member': CLAN_MEMBER_PATH,
    'tournament_info': TOURNAMENT_INFO_PATH,
    'tournament_list': TOURNAMENT_LIST_PATH
}
```

How can i hint right `api_method` parameter, if i need to use one of proposed api methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to my question

```py
class ApiMethod(str, Enum):
  ACCOUNT_INFO = "account_info"
  ...


API_METHODS: typing.Final[dict[ApiMethod, str]] = ...
```

```py
def _get_payload(api_method: ApiMethod) -> ...: ...
```

Comment: You can also use `typing.Literal`, if you don't need enum functionality.